# How to properly define a path to node_modules with polymer 3

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-3.x

How should I define an import section inside my WebComponent with polymer 3.

Currenty I have:

```
import {html, PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
```

and my catalogs structure looks like:
[image: catalogs structure]

and I'm getting an error: 
(index):7 GET http://127.0.0.1:8001/components/ing-dr-plan-details/node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Its not 100% clear where you've placed your polymer config, but I assume you have everything within the folder my-web-component. I.e also your node modules should be within that folder [see also doc](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/start/first-element/intro).

Answer (score 0):

The import code you have

```
import {html, PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
```

and the error does not relate to each other, the terminal is complaining about the missing `@webcomponentsjs` package.

This is due to the fact that in Polymer 3, `@webcomponentsjs` package is not included by default in `dependencies` anymore (it used to be in Polymer 2). You need to manually install `@webcomponentsjs` with:

`npm install @webcomponentsjs`